# Почему размерность увеличивается?

Tags: нейронные-сети

вопрос на засыпку, почему размерность данных начиная с 2d (x,y) увеличивается после каждой свёртки?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Типа каждый фильтр сначала, это грубо говоря мини-признак(граница носа, граница уха), который потом обобщается с другими общими фильтрами-признаками в общие признаки(нос, ухо и т.д.)

Comment: Сначала обобщаем изображение до небольшой кучи признаков (уменьшение размерности), а затем начинаем искать в этом обобщении узкоспециализированные шаблоны (увеличение размерности)?

Comment: "Сначала обобщаем изображение до небольшой кучи признаков, а затем начинаем искать в этом обобщении узкоспециализированные шаблоны?", про признаки и их обобщения я читал, то-есть это получается вот так(тему обновил)?

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос? В чем суть вопроса? Вас интересует - почему технически возрастает размерность тензоров или зачем (для каких целей) это делается?

Comment: @MaxU зачем (для каких целей) ? :*(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> почему (технически) возрастает глубина матриц/тензоров в сверточных нейронных сетях?

Число фильтров в [Conv2D слое](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) задаёт число слоёв в выходном тензоре данного слоя. Например если использовать 64 фильтра, то на выходе получим матрицу глубиной в 64 слоя. Логически, число фильтров задаёт число признаков, которые сеть должна научиться распознавать.

> зачем (с какой целью) увеличивать число фильтров в более глубоких слоях в сверточных сетях?

На начальных слоях СНС (Сверточная Нейронная Сеть) учится распознавать простые признаки, например: горизонтальные, вертикальные, дианональные линиии; дуги и т.д.
На более глубоких слоях СНС учиться комбинировать признаки, выявленные на более ранних слоях для распознавания чуть более сложных признаков, например простых геометрических фигур, созданных из линий/дуг (признаков), полученных на предыдущих слоях. Чем глубже слой, тем более абстрактные/обобщенные признаки он пытается выявить. Чем абстрактнее признак тем сложнее его описать опираясь на комбинацию более простых признаков, поэтому число таких признаков растет от начальных к более глубоким слоям СНС.

Математическая аналогия - для того, чтобы описать прямую в двухмерном пространстве достаточно двух чисел, задающих угол наклона и смещение, для описания более сложных фигур понадобится больше чисел (коэффициентов, переменных) и чем сложнее объект, тем больше информации нам надо, чтобы точно и однозначно его описать.